# I need to clear all rows of a table in my database every time I start/restart JBoss. Is there some way to acc

Tags: hibernate, jboss

I need to clear all rows of one table in my database every time I start/restart JBoss.  I've read that I can put sql statements in Hibernate's 'import.sql' file, and that would work great if I had hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto set to create.  However, I need it to be set to update.  Ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **ServiceMBeanSupport :** An abstract base class JBoss services can subclass to implement a service that conforms to the ServiceMBean
>   interface. Subclasses must override getName() method and should
>   override startService(), and stopService() as approriate.

After implementing the appropriate methods, have to add entry in jboss-service.xml.

```
<server>
<mbean code="com.startup.StartupService" name="com.startup:service=StartupService"> 
</mbean>
</server>
```

In, `startService()`, you can add your custom logic to be performed each time during server startup, executing database operations, scripts etc.